# How can we implement First() function used in Informatica in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, window-functions, informatica, sql-limit

I have an aggregate transformation in Informatica where Description1 column=First(Description).
I want to implement the same in SQL query.Can anyone suggest how to do this?
Sample Dataset
Table name-ABC

```
Name               Expression
ID                 ID
DESCRIPTION 
DESCRIPTION1       FIRST(DESCRIPTION1)
INSERT_DATE 
INSERT_DATE1       FIRST(INSERT_DATE)
RANK    
RANK1              FIRST(RANK)
```

Comment: Please provide your Table name and column name

Comment: Table name is Router_Transform and column name is Description1 and it is equal to First(Description) in Aggregate Transformation in Informatica.I want to write a sql query that allows me to use the functionality of First() function.

Comment: How may columns you have in that table and how many columns are grouped in aggregator transformation?

Comment: There are total 11 columns in this table and we have id column that we are using as a group by condition.We have basically 11 columns that are grouped by id value.

Comment: Fine, below is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select max(Description1) from Router_Transform;
```

If you are using sorter transformation in your Mapping, please use `order by` clause,

```
    select max(Description1) from Router_Transform order by column_name;
```

Comment: I need first value not a max value.

Comment: First() is an aggregator function in Informatica that returns first value of port depending upon ports grouped.

Comment: Informatica passes the data to Aggregator transformation, and it groups the first record when first() function is used according to the sorting order you pass by

Comment: Exactly, there can be many values when you aggregate, if picks up the first value and provides you. Probably you can post your sample data and expected result. Can help you  on this

Comment: I have mentioned a sample dataset in my question

Comment: No basically i need sample data and your expected result

Comment: INPUT DATA  
ID DESCRIPTION RANK
4 India                      2
3 Australia                   1
2 England                   5
1 NewZealand           6
  
Adding DESCRIPTION1=FIRST(DESCRIPTION)  
RANK1=FIRST(RANK)  
Group by ID value

Comment: Expected value is DESCRIPTION1 will give NewZealand as  output because we are grouping by ID (ASC) and likewise RANK1 will give 6 as output.

Comment: Converting informatica transformation to sql is little tricky. If you provide the sample data and expected result, its easy to provide you the solution

Comment: In my previous comment,I have provided a sample dataset along with expected result.

Comment: This one entry will not be useful

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row with the smallest `id`, then you can sort the resultset and retain just one row. In standard SQL, you would typically use a row-limiting clause for this:

```
select t.*
from mytable
order by id
fetch first row only
```

Note that all databases support this syntax (but almost all have alternatives for that).

On the other hand, if you want to add more columns to each row that display the "first" value for each column, then you would use window function `first_value()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    first_value(description) over(order by id) description1,
    first_value(insert_date) over(order by id) insert_date1,
    first_value(rank)        over(order by id) rank1
from mytable
```

Comment: @Vilas: is there any reason why you unaccepted this answer?